# Azure DevOps API - Retrieve global lists

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are currently using an on premise TFS 2018 installation and there are a couple of custom applications that use the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient in order to communicate with TFS. Now since some assemblies in the extended client are going to be deprecated ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-the-deprecation-of-the-wit-and-test-client-om-at-jan-1-2020-2/)) and a move to Azure DevOps services is a possibility I have started checking the replacement ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops))

In our current implementation we are using global lists and extendedClient WorkItemStore had the  ExportGlobalLists/ImportGlobalLists methods that were handy

The problem is that I cannot find an equivalent method in the new client

- is witadmin the only option?
- I have found this in the REST API ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processdefinitions/lists/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)) but it doesn't seem to work for on-premise so I could test it out

Any ideas would be welcome

Comment: Are you looking for this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processdefinitions/lists/list?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll keep that in mind but I see that the rest calls refer to picklists and I do not utilize those in the on-prem installations (I have a 2018 U2 and 2019 test env) hence this is not working. The ExportGlobalList method works on both environments. Funny they stripped this capability since Global lists it is still supported in the on-prem installations

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no concept of a global list any more in Azure DevOps Services.  If you want to customize the fields, it is usually defining the available list on the field.

We are utilizing the lists on-premise Azure DevOps Server 2019, but only ever interact to get them from witadmin.

Answer (score 0):

According the comment in this case:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312980/cannot-edit-existing-global-lists.html?childToView=338672#comment-338672

> Global lists are now part of a specific work item. To edit the list
>   you should 1) export the process 2) look into the xml for the work
>   items. Global lists are usually added to the bug or task wit 3) make
>   the global list changes in the xml 4) zip up the process and import
>   back into Azure DevOps.

Comment: I went through the post but it refers to VSTS, my question is for the on-prem. So global lists are not supported in the online and are integrated in the wit xml template... That's good to know in case of a possible migration  (and guessing from the final response and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work?view=azure-devops-2019 witadmin is also not an option in Azure DevOps services)

Comment: You may check [WorkItemStore.ExportGlobalLists Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb140386(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and [WorkItemStore.ImportGlobalLists Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb140395(v=vs.120)) for on-premise TFS.

Comment: Those methods are part of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll which I believe based on the first link of the post are marked as deprecated. This is how I've been doing it so far. But now I'm looking for a way to execute the same task with the new api

Comment: Deprecation means that any new features for Azure Boards or Azure Test will not be added into the Client OM. You are still able to use the SOAP api to export/import global list.